# String.replaceAll(regex) makes the same replacement twice

Tags: java, regex

Can anyone tell me why

```
System.out.println("test".replaceAll(".*", "a"));
```

Results in

```
aa
```

Note that the following has the same result:

```
System.out.println("test".replaceAll(".*$", "a"));
```

I have tested this on java 6 & 7 and both seem to behave the same way.
Am I missing something or is this a bug in the java regex engine?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

This is not an anomaly: `.*` can match anything.

You ask to replace all occurrences:

- the first occurrence does match the whole string, the regex engine therefore starts from the end of input for the next match;
- but `.*` also matches an empty string! It therefore matches an empty string at the end of the input, and replaces it with `a`.

Using `.+` instead will not exhibit this problem since this regex cannot match an empty string (it requires at least one character to match).

Or, use `.replaceFirst()` to only replace the first occurrence:

```
"test".replaceFirst(".*", "a")
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Now, why `.*` behaves like it does and *does not match more than twice* (it theoretically could) is an interesting thing to consider. See below:

```
# Before first run
regex: |.*
input: |whatever
# After first run
regex: .*|
input: whatever|
#before second run
regex: |.*
input: whatever|
#after second run: since .* can match an empty string, it it satisfied...
regex: .*|
input: whatever|
# However, this means the regex engine matched an empty input.
# All regex engines, in this situation, will shift
# one character further in the input.
# So, before third run, the situation is:
regex: |.*
input: whatever<|ExhaustionOfInput>
# Nothing can ever match here: out
```

Note that, as @A.H. notes in the comments, not all regex engines behave this way. GNU `sed` for instance will consider that it has exhausted the input after the first match.

Comment: Agreed. This is true for Perl too. `perl -le '$x = "test"; $x =~ s/.*/a/g; print $x'` yields "aa".

Comment: @ChrisDolan: `sed` yields only `a`, but I doubt its a bug. :-)

Comment: @A.H. yes indeed... I need to read "Mastering Regular Expressions" again

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I've been using regexes for a long time but never ran into this one. Learn something new every day...

Comment: Another way to solve this: Use `^.*` - this will only match `a` once for obvious reasons.

Comment: Is this [buggy] behavior still the same after this fix?: https://bugs.openjdk.org/browse/JDK-7189363

Answer (score 2):

The accepted answer hasn't shown this yet, so here is an alternative way to fix your regex:

```java
System.out.println("test".replaceAll("^.*$", "a"));
```

Note, I'm using both terminators: `^` and `$`. The `$` isn't strictly necessary for this particular case, but I find adding both least cryptic.