# Why does preg_replace with /(.*)/ repeat part of string?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Why does the following code:

```
<?php echo preg_replace("/(.*)/", "$1.def", "abc");
```

Output `abc.def.def` instead of `abc.def`?

I'm interested in understanding why the repetition occurs.

Using `/(.+)/` or `/^(.*)$/` works as expected, but I'm not looking for a solution, just asking a question (although these patterns may be related to the answer).

Tinker with a live version [here](http://codepad.org/DbVBGgx9).

Comment: Simpler test case - [`<?php echo preg_replace("/.*/", "b", "a");`](http://codepad.org/Ol3Bz4Zo)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604286/java-regex-anomaly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because `.*` matches the empty substring at the end of the string. It means there are two matches to the string `abc`:

1. The whole string `abc` → `abc.def`
2. The empty string → `.def`

which gives `abc.def.def`.

---

**Edit:** Detail of why it happens is explained in  *[String.replaceAll() anomaly with greedy quantifiers in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604286/java-regex-anomaly)*.

Comment: Why does it not match the entire string the first time? If I run `"a".replace(/.*/, "b")` in javascript, I get the expected `b`. If I do `preg_replace("/.*/", "b", "a")` in php, I get `bb`.

Comment: @Eric: `"a".replace(/.*/g, "b")`.

Comment: Strange expected behaviour. I would have thought that the `.*` match would consume as much as possible including any empty string at the end. Is there not an empty string after that empty string? :)

Comment: Whoops! I'd forgotten about that.

Comment: What is an 'Empty Substring'?

Comment: is it specific to PCRE ? The ruby version `"a".sub(/.*/, 'b')` that uses another regex engine yields 'b'

Comment: @SirDarius: `"a".gsub(/.*/, 'b')`

Comment: ah, my bad, so this is behaviour coming from at least two regex engines

Comment: Can someone confirm that there is only a single instance of an empty string at the end of the subject string? Because as many people have pointed out, why isn't there an empty string at the beginning? My understanding so far is that it's there on purpose as a sort of hook to match against.

Comment: @matb33: The empty string does not happen in the beginning because the match is greedy. If it is non-greedy then it would match the empty string at the beginning, as pointed out in [@dda's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10820150/224671).

Answer (score 3):

It's the expected behaviour: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=53855

> This is expected behaviour and nothing peculiar to PHP.  The *
>   quantifier allows  an "empty" match to occur at the end of your
>   subject string.

Answer (score 2):

If you make your regex non-greedy, `/(.*?)/` you can see the whole process of repetition working on a much larger/noticeable scale:

```
.defa.defb.defc.def
```

You get four matches: a, b, c, `empty`. Whereas, as other people mentioned, with a greedy regex, you get 2 matches, the full string, and an empty string.

Comment: But why doesn't the greedy version grab the whole thing as a match - including the empty string?

Comment: Because when it starts matching something ('abc' in this case) it can't "add" an empty string to a non-empty string. Whereas once it's done with the non-empty string, it **can** match an empty string.

Comment: Sorry to hear that, buddy... But then again, regexes can be mystifying.

Comment: Why isn't there another empty string after the empty string?

Comment: Because it's like the Highlander, There Can Be Only One.

Comment: @trapper I think it's the defined behavior of regex, i.e. to provide a single empty string at the end of the subject string (as noted in the quote by @dAm2K). I'm guessing it's there to be used as a hook for some fancy regex'ing