# Java replaceAll with backreferences

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [String.replaceAll() anomaly with greedy quantifiers in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8604286/string-replaceall-anomaly-with-greedy-quantifiers-in-regex)

I was writing code that uses `Matcher#replaceAll` and found following result highly confusing:

```java
Pattern.compile("(.*)").matcher("sample").replaceAll("$1abc");
```

Now, I would expect the output to be `sampleabc` but Java throws at me `sampleabcabc`.

Does anybody have any ideas why?

Now, sure, when I anchor the pattern (`^(.*)$`) the issue goes away. Still I don't know why the hell would `replaceAll` do a double replacement like that.

And to add insult to injury, following code:

```java
Pattern.compile("(.*)").matcher("sample").replaceFirst("$1abc")
```

works as expected, returning just `sampleabc`.

Comment: @Pshemo: you are right. I'm sorry I failed to find this prior submission.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like it's matching the empty string at the end of the input, for some reason. (I can see why it would match; I'm intrigued that it matches *once* and only once.)

If you change `replaceAll("$1abc")` to `replaceAll("'$1'abc")` the result is `'sample'abc''abc`.

Note that if you change `(.*)` to `(.+)` then it works correctly, because it has to match at least one character.

The diagnosis is confirmed by this code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(.*)").matcher("sample");

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.printf("%d to %d\r\n", 
                      matcher.start(), 
                      matcher.end());
}
```

... which outputs:

```
0 to 6
6 to 6
```

Comment: +1 first to answer _and_ to give solution...

Comment: I could not find where is documented that you can refer to a capturing group result with $1, $2 etc in the "replace with" string. In the Pattern javadoc is said that you refer with '\1', '\2' etc.

Comment: @George: That's because you're looking in `Pattern` javadoc rather than in [`Matcher.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-) which states: "Dollar signs may be treated as references to captured subsequences as described above, and backslashes are used to escape literal characters in the replacement string." See the docs for `appendReplacement` for the "as described above" part.

Answer (score 5):

There are two things going on here that explain why this happens:

- `(.*)` will successfully match empty strings.
- After a match succeeds, another match will be attempted one position after the end of the previous match.

So, after the entire string `"sample"` is matched, another match is attempted just after the `e`.  Even though there are no characters left the match succeeds and a second replacement occurs.

Additional replacements do not occur because the regex engine will always move forward.  Just after the last character is a valid starting index so the empty string will match once, but after the empty string is matched there are no more valid starting positions for the regex engine to attempt a match from.

As an alternative to adding a beginning of string anchor to your regex, you can modify your regex so it matches one or more character by changing `(.*)` to `(.+)`.