# Matcher creates extra group at the end of string

Tags: java, regex

I've faced with strange behavior of java.util.regex.Matcher.
Lets consider example:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d*");
    String s = "a1b";
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.start()+" "+m.end());
    }
```

It produces output:

```
0 0
1 2
2 2
3 3
```

I can understant all lines except last. Matcher creates extra group (3,3) out of string.
But javadoc for method start() confirms:

> start() Returns the start index of the previous match.

The same case for dot-star pattern:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*");
String s = "a1b";
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    System.out.println(m.start()+" "+m.end());
}
```

Output:

```
0 3
3 3
```

But if specify line boundaries

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^.*$");
```

The output will be "right":

```
0 3
```

Can someone explain me а reason of such behavior?

Comment: `*` signifies 0 or more. Nothing is 0.

Comment: Have you tried changing `*` to `+`?

Comment: Also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8604286/1393766) may interest you a little.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern `"\\d*"` matches 0 or more digits. Same stands for `".*"`. It matches 0 or more occurrence of any character except newline.

The last match that you get is the empty string at the end of your string, after `"b"`. The empty string satisfies the pattern `\\d*`. If you change the pattern to `\\d+`, you'll get expected result.

Similarly, the pattern `.*` matches everything from first character to last character. Thus it first matches `"a1b"`. After that the cursor is after `b`: `"a1b|"`. Now, `matcher.find()` again runs, and finds a zero-length string at the cursor, which satisifies the pattern `.*`, so it considers it as a match.

The reason why it gives expected output with `"^.*$"` is that the last empty string doesn't satisfy the `^` anchor. It is not at the beginning of the string, so it fails to match.

Comment: Yes, you are right about \\d+ , but what "empty string" do you mean? I   didn't see any in javadocs.

Comment: @user3516622 Empty string is the one after the last character of the string. Technically, there is an empty character after and before every character in a string.